# What's the maximum distance that a radio wave can travel at full power

Tags: radiation, vacuum, space, wavelength, radio

If the sun is eight minutes away if you are travelling at the speed of light, since that's how long it would take for people to notice if the sun had stopped shining, how far can a short-wave radio signal travel in a vacuum at full power versus a long wave radio signal?

Think of radio communication on other planets, like humans possibly going to Mars.

Comment: In vacuum, no difference. Note that light is really short wavelength radio waves...

Comment: @JonCuster - The designation *shortwave radio* waves is reserved to the high frequency band 1.7–30 MHz (Wavelengths 176.3–10.0 m). Thus visible light with frequencies 430–750 terahertz (THz) or wavelengths 0.4 to 0.7 $\mu m$ is definitely not included in this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortwave_radio

Comment: What does the sun have to do with it? What does "at full power" mean? Are you asking "How far can a signal at full power travel?" Are you "How far can a signal travel while remaining at full power?"

Comment: @freecharly, "shortwave" is a specific band. "Short wavelengths" just means wavelengths that are short. Light definitely has short wavelengths compared to radio.

Comment: @ThePhoton - There is no doubt about this. But the OP asked specifically about short-wave radio signals as compared to a long wave radio signal. And light is no short-wave radio signal with or without hyphen.

Comment: @freecharly - as an Amateur Extra licensed ham radio operator, I'm well aware of the (quite variable mind you!) frequency designators. The point was that light is light in vacuum, whether rf, visible, or gamma...

Comment: @JonCuster - Sorry that my comments created this wrong impression. I knew that the intention  of your short comment was to explain to the OP that light was nothing else than very short wavelength electromagnetic waves.  I made this comment only in regard to the question of the OP who specifically addressed the difference between short-wave and long wave radio signals.

Comment: @freecharly - no problem. Sometimes people focus on a narrow distinction when they should be thinking more broadly. No, too broad has its own issues... (And, us semiconductor physics folks need to stick together - we are outnumbered!).

Comment: @JonCuster - You are completely right!

Comment: What does the sun being 8 light minutes away from earth have to do with whether short-wave vs long-wave can travel further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just asking about distance, there is no theoretical limit to how far a radio wave can travel. Regarding communicating between Earth and Mars, yup, we've already done that with several instruments, i.e. orbiters and rovers we've sent there.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of all electromagnetic waves in vacuum is equal to the speed of light. Thus all radio waves, i.e., longwave, shortwave, ultra-short wave radio waves, microwave waves; light waves, i.e., infrared to visible and ultra-violet light; and  x-ray and gamma-ray waves all propagate at the same speed of approximately 300000 km/s. Thus radio signals to the sun would take the same 8 minutes as visible light.